# Videos sorted by relevance with more views than sorted by View count on YouTube

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to implement a search of **the most popular videos by tag** with Youtube API v3, and encountered a problem when videos sorted by `Relevance` have more views than those that were sorted by `View count`.

```
export const videoList = async (p = null, args: any): Promise<VideoItems | undefined> => {
try {
    const {q, maxResults = 5} = args || {};
    const youtube = google.youtube({auth: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_API_KEY, version: 'v3'});

    const resp: any = await youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        order: 'relevance',
        relevanceLanguage: 'en',
        regionCode: 'us',
        type: 'video',
        q: `#${q}`,
        maxResults
    });

    return {
        items: resp?.data?.items?.map((item: VideoItem) => (
            {id: item?.id?.videoId, title: item?.snippet?.title})
        )
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

This behavior is reproduced in a native YouTube search:

By relevance: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%23Equality+of+triangles&sp=CAA%253D

By View count: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%23Equality+of+triangles&sp=CAM%253D

1. Is there a better way to get the most popular videos by tag with high numbers of views other than `order: 'relevance'`?
2. Why do videos sorted by relevance have more views than those sorted by View count?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, tbh. Consider check in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) if there is a ticket posted there, otherwise, you can also post a ticket there and wait for an official answer.